# Reducing time complexity in Perl arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl, math

I am having a array

```
[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6]
```

I want to sort ( Changed `sort` to `arranging in a certain pattern`) this as : Move to right and replace the index with next highest integer on right side. Say in this array `3` is replaced by `5`, 1 is replaced by `2` and so on..

I want the output as

```
[5, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

Algorithm :

1. Start a forloop. It will iterate till last element
2. Starting from first index it will match with next index and compare the value
3. If second index is less than first then move to third index
4. If not change the first index with second index
5. Try with all the indexes

It is a normal algorithm. But the time complexity is n*n. (No exactly n*n).

Is there a way to reduce the complexity. Because in case of large arrays, it would be very slow. Can somebody provide me algorithm for time complexity `n`.

Adding code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr1 = qw/3 1 2 5 4 6/;
my @arr2;
my ($j, $i);
for($i = 0; $i <= $#arr1; $i++) {
    $j = $i;
    while ( $j < $#arr1) {
        if ( $arr1[$i] < $arr1[$j+1]) {
            push @arr2,$arr1[$j+1];
            last;
        } 
        if ($i == $#arr1) {
            push @arr2,$arr1[$j];
        }
        $j++;
    }

}
push @arr2, $arr1[$#arr1];   ## Pushing the last array index

print @arr2;
```

Output:

`525666`

Comment: Please show the code you have already written for reference.

Comment: @simbabque: Code is not important here. Asking to reduce time complexity. Only algo will be suffice

Comment: @Nitesh: if the algo is sufficient and the code is not important, you should not tag the question with `perl`.

Comment: Or you should move your question to [programmers.se] because it's better suited for those guys.

Comment: @simbabque: do u know how to do this? I feel algo that i have given is quite good enough to understand. I am not asking error in the code. I am asking another approach. Without iteration

Comment: This is homework, right?

Comment: @simbabque: Not a homework. Just wondering how to do this. Frankly speaking i am in testing. We dont really care about time complexity. But i thought as a developer perspective. Asking for my knowledge. I even know it can be solved with stack datastructure.

Comment: A clue: Start at the other end of the array. You only need to hold two values then: previous seen (before replacing), and current descending value.

Comment: Your attempt to describe the problem in English is rather convoluted. As @simbabque said, please provide code for a sample implementation, as that will give an exact explanation of what you're doing.

Comment: @simbabque, Dave, Neil: Please check my code

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Perl  or use the built in "sort" function

Comment: @Vorsprung: This is not a sort

Comment: sorry I was put off by the use of the word "sort" in the description!

Comment: @Vorsprung : Yes not a sorting. But arranging in a certain pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current algorithm can touch one position multiple times, which is inefficient. By the power of recursion, we could do better. Imagine a function that performs your sort until it finds a number higher than some `$n`:

```
[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6] # start here
#^
[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6] # look at next number. It's smaller, so we recurse
#^--^
[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6] # in recursion: look at next number, replace
#^  ^--^
#|__|
[3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 6] # return new index. It's smaller, so we recurse
#^     ^
#|_____|
[3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 6] # in recursion: look at next number, replace
#^     ^--^
#|_____|
[3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6] # return new index
#^        ^
#|________|
[3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6] # It's larger, so we replace and go to new index
#^--------^
[5, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6] # Look at next number. It's smaller, so we recurse
#         ^--^
[5, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6] # In recursion: replace
#         ^  ^--^
#         |__|
[5, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6] # return new index
#         ^     ^
#         |_____|
[5, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6] # It's larger, so we replace. Go to new index
#         ^-----^
[5, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6] # Done!
```

The difficult part is to write a function that does this. As we want to write a recursive function, we have to think backwards:

- `[]` – empty array (no indices left) sorts to itself
- `[6]` – array with single element left sorts to that element
- `[4, 6] → [6, 6]` – if the element at the next index is larger, copy it over and the new index is at the next element
- `[5, 4, ...]` – if the next element is smaller, recurse at that index.

Example implementation:

```
sub weird_sort {
  my ($array, $start, $return) = @_;
  $start //= 0;
  my $next = $start + 1;

  while ($next <= $#$array) {
    # check if one is larger
    if ($array->[$start] < $array->[$next]) {
      $array->[$start] = $array->[$next];
      return $next if $return;  # return index to higher levels so that they
                                # can check whether the $next elem is larger.
      $start = $next;
      $next  = $start + 1;
    }
    else {
      $next = weird_sort($array, $next, 1);
    }
  }

  return $next;
}

# called in-place like
weird_sort(\@array);
```

The next step would be to remove the recursion:

```
sub weird_sort {
  my ($array) = @_;
  my ($start, $next) = (0, 1);

  my @stack;

  while ($next <= $#$array) {
    # check if one is larger
    if ($array->[$start] < $array->[$next]) {
      $array->[$start] = $array->[$next];
      ($start, $next) = @stack ? (pop(@stack), $next) : ($next, $next + 1);
    }
    else {
      push @stack, $start;
      ($start, $next) = ($next, $next + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to work for simple cases, but I'm not entirely certain that this is a general solution.

Comment: With the 1 million elements as shown in my answer below this solution is approx 3 times as fast as the original.  Good stuff.

Comment: +1 for describing the question better than the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is N*N complexity. The average distance to a larger value does not increase as the array grows, so your complexity increases at the rate of N not N*N. Why don't you post some code? If it is taking a long time to evaluate, perhaps you have an error in your implementation.

Comment: This is useful advice, but not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: Yes, complexity is  not exactly N*N. But close to that. N iterations and goes till N times. So N*N in case the array entered is equal to desired array

Comment: @Nitesh: Technically a purely descending array (with no substitutions) would take O( N*N ) to process  using your algroithm. But a statistically random array is more like O( N ) - the average distance to next max on a uniform distribution is ~ 0.7.

Comment: @Neil : Can we make it to `N`. Using stacks may be

Comment: @Nitesh: Yes. No need for stacks. Just start at the other end of the array, and consider what the minimum knowledge is that you would then need to process each item in turn. The important detail is that you will have already seen that data at each step, so only pass through the list once with no secondary loop.

Comment: @NeilSlater: How it will help. By your approach we will not get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

By not using a new array for the reordered data your existing algorithm goes faster.  With the test program below on my laptop this is about 60% faster with 1 million elements mildly randomized

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#my @arr1 = qw/3 1 2 5 4 6/;
my @arr1= ( 1 .. 1000000 );
for (@arr1) { my $r1=rand($#arr1); my $r2=rand($#arr1); @arr1[$r1,$r2]=@arr1[$r2,$r1] }
my @arr2;
my ($j, $i);
for($i = 0; $i <= $#arr1; $i++) {
    $j = $i;
    while ( $j < $#arr1) {
        if ( $arr1[$i] < $arr1[$j+1]) {
            $arr1[$i] = $arr1[$j+1];
            last;
        } 
        $j++;
    }

}

#print @arr1;
```